# Print for loop input filename on piped awk output

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk, samtools

I wish to print $fname on each line of awk the ouput for the following:

```
for fname in $(ls *.bam | cut -c -9 | uniq)
    do
    echo $fname
    samtools depth  -a "$fname".bam | awk '{sum+=$3} END {print "Average = ", sum/NR}' >> mean.depth
    done
```

Current output:

```
$ less mean.depth  
    Average =  5.40089
    Average =  4.68387
```

Desired output:

```
$ less mean.depth  
    FILENAME1 Average =  5.40089
    FILENAME2 Average =  4.68387
```

So that the output mean depths are traceable. I've tried FILENAME and all sorts of things but not succeeding. Thanks!

Comment: since awk is acting upon stdin, FILENAME won't work... pass the shell variable containing filename, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @GMK: Since you found a solution, you should post it as an answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Define shell variable $fname  with `awk -v var=`, then print it with `END {print var`

```
samtools depth  -a "$fname".bam | awk -v var=$fname '{sum+=$3} END {print var, " = ", sum/NR}' >> mean.depth
```